# Grails - What is the use of application.properties

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I read that application.properties file you can access with g:meta tag and grials interface Meta class. That is fine but, I see some of sample projects like this

```
plugins.export=1.5
plugins.google-visualization=0.5.6
plugins.jquery-ui=1.8.24
plugins.markdown=1.0.0.RC1
plugins.svn=1.0.0.M1
```

What is the use of mension version in this file. Please let me know what exact use of this file please.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the stone age, plugin dependencies were listed in `application.properties` as per your example. But this was changed (a long time ago), and they should now be listed in `BuildConfig.groovy`. Normally, `application.properties` only defines the following

```
# the version of Grails that should be used
app.grails.version=2.4.3

# the name of the app
app.name=myapp

# the version of the servlet API that should be used
app.servlet.version=3.0

# the version of your app
app.version=0.1
```